# Using multiple Sublime packages that utilize the gutter

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, pylint, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using Sublime Text and I have these two awesome packages: Pylinter and GitGutter. The problem is that they both use the gutter (the thin space just to the left of the line numbers).

Currently, GitGutter's gutter icons trump Pylinter's gutter icons, but I would like it to be the other way around, so that I can see the errors Pylinter points out, regardless of what GitGutter is saying about that same line. How can I achieve this?

(For now, my Pylinter settings are such that it outlines in white any offending lines instead of putting an icon in the gutter. So I do have a solution that allows me to use both Pylinter and GitGutter, but I would prefer to have Pylinter gutter icons instead of the white outlines.)

Answer (score 2):

Bugs have been filed on both the GitGutter ([issue #113](https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter/issues/113)) and SublimeLinter ([issue #554](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-for-ST2/issues/554)) Github issue trackers for this. As it stands, this has been a known issue for a couple of years.

The GitGutter author has been attempting to fix this during that time and the issue is still open. If you look at the conversation on Github, you'll see the last work on this was about a month ago. The comments show that they believe it works correctly now, but that issue has already been closed once before, only to be opened back up.

The SublimeLinter author on the other hand, [doesn't believe this can be fixed](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-for-ST2/issues/554) and has closed the issue.

> I don’t think anything can be done about this. Sublime Text will only display one gutter icon on a given line, and if two plugins draw an icon on the same line, it is indeterminate which one will draw first because the linting is triggered in a separate thread. The same issue arises with other plugins that draw gutter marks, such as BracketHighlighter.

Comment: I hope someday in the future Sublime can support multiple gutters just like VSCode gutters.